# Raise custom exception for incorrect header Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am building a Flask REST API which does not have a front-end yet. I've successfully developed a GET request for a Flask view that fetches all the subscribers from the SQL database. I'm using the same Flask view to `INSERT` `VALUES` through POST requests to the database. To sanitize the input, I've used `(%s)` as placeholder for the values. Below are excerpts from the code:

```
#main.py
@app.route('/api/subscribe/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def subscribe():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        try:
            data = DB.get_subscription_list()
            return Response(json.dumps({'result': data}, cls=DateTimeEncoder, sort_keys=True), mimetype='application/json')
        except Exception as e:
            return e
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            email = request.form.get('email')
            data = DB.add_email(email)
            return Response(json.dumps({'result': 'Email added to database'}, cls=DateTimeEncoder, sort_keys=True), mimetype='application/json')
        except Exception as e:
            return e


#dbhelper.py
def add_email(self,data):
    connection = self.connect()
    try:
        #The following adds an email entry to the 'users' table.
        query = "INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES (%s);"
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(query,data)
            connection.commit()
    except pymysql.ProgrammingError as e:
        print(e)
        raise e   
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

I have edited this question with more precise information and specific to my problem.

I am currently testing the API on RESTClient and Postman.

When I send a POST request with header `{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}`, the value inserts successfully. Output: `{"result": "Email added to database"}`. If this header is not used, I get a Programmingerror exception below:

`(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1")`

How can I raise a custom exception for the incorrect header entry so that it raises this custom exception rather than show a syntax error?Of course, this is not a syntax error as the value is inserted successfully when using the *urlencoded* header.

Comment: you are printing the exception and not raising one! below print(e) add raise e

Comment: Yes, this now at least returns the error. This is not a Programming error, but something to do with the header parameter. Flask does not identify header errors? I would like to raise a Programming error exception and a header exception separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by creating custom error handlers for each error status code. I realized that the *mimetype* `{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}` header is required when I use `request.form.get()`. This is because the information in the form is encoded when it is sent to the server. I have now used `request.json.get()` as I would like to send the data in `json` instead, the header now required is `{'Content-Type':'application/json'}` *mimetype*. So, now my view looks like this:

```
#subscribe.py
@app.route('/api/users/subscribe', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def subscribe():
    if request.method == "GET":
        try:
            data = DB.get_subscription_list()
            return Response(json.dumps({'result': data}, cls=DateTimeEncoder, sort_keys=True), mimetype='application/json', status=200)
        except Exception:
            return Response(json.dumps({'error': 'Could not fetch subscribers from database.'}), status=500)
    elif request.method == "POST":
        try:
            email = request.json.get("email")
            data = DB.add_email(email)
            return Response(json.dumps({'result': 'Email added to database.'}, cls=DateTimeEncoder, sort_keys=True), mimetype='application/json', status=201)
        except Exception:
            return Response(json.dumps({'error': 'Could not add to database.'}), status=500)
```

Notice, the custom error exception above for each method. I also created custom error handlers in cases where an error appears with a status code and I haven't explicitly defined an exception for them . For example, if I get an error with status code 500 which renders in `html`, the error handler below will show a custom error in `json`. I've added similar error handlers for status codes 405, 401 etc. so that I always get custom errors in`json`.

```
@app.errorhandler(500)
def method_not_allowed(error):
    return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'An error occurred during a request'}), 500)
```

Similarly, I added an exception for database queries:

```
#dbhelper.py
try:
    #The following adds an email entry to the 'users' table.
    uri = url_for('subscribe', email=email, _external=True)
    query = "INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES (%s);"
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(query,email)
        connection.commit()
except Exception:  
    return Response(json.dumps({'error':'Database connection error.'}), status=500)
```

Now, I was getting `json` exceptions when I don't send data in json or invalid data in my POST requests. There are no `Programmingerrors` anymore as I have corrected my code to respond with desired results.

A more organized way is to define custom error classes in a separate `errors.py` file and call the exception functions whenever necessary.